# Node.js Use XMLHttpRequest POST 404 Error

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest

I meet Node.js POST Method error 404 wrong. Details:

System platform: Windows 7 ultimate
Mid-level control:XAMPP V3.2.4
Apache: PHP5.2
Node.js:node-v11.0.0-x64.msi
Node-module image:[Node-module directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zGMW.jpg)

Files:
**app.js**

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var oracledb = require('oracledb');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();


app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
res.locals.message = err.message;
res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
res.status(err.status || 500);
res.render('error');
});
app.listen(3000,function(){
console.log('listening port 3000');
});
module.exports = app;
```

**login.js**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-cn"  class="login">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Node Blog</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="Node,Node.js">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>
<body>
<section>
<form action="/login" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="登录名" onBlur="getData()">
<script type="text/javascript">
   
    var url = 'http://localhost:3000/login';

    function getData() {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        document.write('readyState:');//4 sentences for testing execute result as below:
        document.write(this.readyState);
        document.write('status:');
        document.write(this.status);
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                 document.write('readyState and status are OK');
            }
        };
      
        xhr.open('POST',url,false);
        xhr.send("username=[user]&password=[password]");
    }
      </script>
        <%if(message){%>
        <p><%=message%></p>
        <%}%>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="密码">
 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="登录">
    </div>
</form>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var indexmain = express.Router();
var crypto = require('crypto');
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var querystring=require("querystring");

indexmain.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST");
    res.setHeader("X-Powered-By","3.2.1");
    res.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json;charset=utf-8");
    let data='';
    console.log('接收到请i去。。。。');
    document.write('createSerrver is connected');// for output the result of testing OK.
    //接收数据
    req.on('data',function(chunk){
      data+=chunk;
    });
    //接受完毕
    req.on('end',function(){
    
    var arr=data.split('&');
    let name,password;//保存前端传递来的数据
    arr.forEach(function(item){
        let arr0=item.split('=');
        if(arr0[0]=='username'){
            name=arr0[1];
        }else if(arr0[0]=='password'){
            password=arr0[1];
        }
     });
  
    //将数据存入数据库
    saveData(name,password,function(msg){
        res.write(JSON.stringify(msg));
        res.end();
     });
   });
});

function saveData(name,password){

   oracledb.getConnection(
   {
        user          : [user],
        password      : [password],
        connectString : [connectString]
   },
   function(err, connection)
   {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        return;
    }
    else{
        console.log('connect OK!');

        var name = req.body.name;
        var password = req.body.password;
        var hash = crypto.createHash('md5');
        var message;
        hash.update(password);
    
   
        connection.execute(
            'SELECT NAME,PASSWORD FROM GUEST',  // bind value for :id
            
            function(err, result)
            {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err.message);
                    return;
                }
                
                var columnslength=result.rows[0].length;
                var judge = 0;//判断用户名是否存在
                for(var i=0;i<result.rows.length;i++){
                    if(name==result.rows[i][0]){
                        judge=1;
                        if(password==result.rows[i][columnslength-1]){
                            
                            res.render('index',{title:"Express"});
                            break;
                        }
                        else{
                            res.render('login',{message:'Password is not correct'});
                            break;
                        }
                    
                    }else{
                        continue;
                    }
                    
                }
                if (judge == 0){
                    res.render('login',{message:'Username is not correct'});
                }
            }
        ) 
        
    }   
}
  
};
});

/* GET home page. */
indexmain.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
 res.render('login', { message: 'hello' });
});

module.exports = indexmain;
```

**Homepage**

[Homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zGMW.jpg)

[Console Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0QWs.jpg)

[image]
[image]

**Problem**
1.No receive data from login.js
Description:In index.js, the createServer() can not obtain the 'xhr.send("username=[username]&   password=[password]")' from login.js. (Testing:The sentence as below can not be excuted)

```
document.write('createSerrver is connected');
```

2.status 0,404 error
Description:In the second Image, the output shows the status. The status continuesly stop at '0' or '404' .

I analyze above error, and conclude as below:

1. php.ini or httpd.conf should be modified with some paramenters about http.
2. In Programming, there exists some issue.

Could you help me to modify some setting in Apache or code in Programming?(The compile for program does not exist error)

Chen Chao

chougou1982@hotmail.com
15021734016@139.com

Comment: (i) in a web app you really need to use a connection pool.  (ii) Your code will be simpler to debug and get correct if you swap to async/await style instead of callbacks.  Look at all the current [node-oracledb examples](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples).